# Oculus development Kit 2 headset design, main PCB cutout

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication

I've been reviewing the Oculus development Kit 2 headset design. [Files here](https://github.com/facebookarchive/riftdk2)

There is a cutout in the PCB that confuses me.  It's 1mm wide and there isn't any notch or anything on the assembly to fit inside.

The U11 is MPU-6500 (3-axis Gyroscope and 3-axis accelerometer) and U12 is LIS3MDL (3-axis magnetometer). They are connected through SPI to the main pic.

My guess is that the cutout is to isolate these chips from any type of noise but I think a simple cutout on the layers would be enough and this is a bit excessive.

Does anyone have another idea about the purpose of this cutout?

[image]

[image]

Comment: more likely to isolate somewhat from mechanical noise

Comment: @ratchetfreak: the thing is meant to pick up movement and position of the whole device, isn't it? doesnt make much sense to try to decouple from there then, especially since now you have a small part with its own rather high resonance. I would have a look at the case, maybe there is a plastic slot in there that it needs to fit into?

Comment: The step of the housing is available as well. I couldn't see any plastic slot to fit there.

Comment: The uart connector is on the other side of the slot, You don't want any tugs on the wire to translate over to the accelerometer.